# Invalid object name 'testing1'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)") in fastapi

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, fastapi

I have created a fastapi project, when I am trying to access data from database, I am getting this error

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'testing1'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: SELECT testing1.id, testing1.name
FROM testing1]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

models.py

```
from typing import Optional

from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel


class Testing(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'testing1'
    
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from sqlmodel import Session, select

from app.database import get_db
from app.models.testing import Testing

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/test")
async def get_test(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    statement = select(Testing)
    result = db.exec(statement)
    return result.all()
```

could someone please tell me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Have you actually created the table in the database? (In SQLModel you do this using `SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)`)

Comment: Adding SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine) in main.py solved this issue. Thanks @M.O.